# Changing text color in a new defined environment in LaTex

Tags: formatting, color

I had defined a new example environment in my LaTex code and I want to change the color of the detail of the example automatically. I had tried to use the package `xcolor` and defined the color in the new environment (by inserting \color{Mahogany} in [] after \newenvironment{exa}[1]) but it doesn't work.

Here is a MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage[dvipsnames]{xcolor}
\newcounter{exa}[section]
\newenvironment{exa}[1][]{\refstepcounter{exa}\par\medskip 
\noindent \textbf{Example ~\theexa. #1} \rmfamily }{\medskip}
\begin{document}
\section{Introduction}
\begin{exa}[I want to color this text] This is an example. 
\end{exa}
\end{document}
```

Please help me. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not quite sure where you were trying to put the `\color` but this works (assuming one spells `Mahogany` correctly `:-)`)

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[dvipsnames]{xcolor}

\newcounter{exa}[section]
\newenvironment{exa}[1][]{%
   \refstepcounter{exa}\par\medskip\noindent
   \textbf{Example ~\theexa. \textcolor{Mahogany}{#1}} %<-- You are introducing a space here
   \rmfamily % <-- I don't quite see the point of this
   \ignorespaces
 }{\par\medskip}

\begin{document}
\section{Introduction}
\begin{exa}[I want to color this text]
This is an example. 
\end{exa}
\end{document}
```

[image]

I would choose the spacing as follows, but this is just my taste.

```
\newenvironment{exa}[1][]{%
   \refstepcounter{exa}\par\medskip\noindent
   \textbf{Example ~\theexa.}
   \if\relax\detokenize{#1}\relax\else\enspace\textcolor{Mahogany}{\bfseries#1}\fi
   \rmfamily % <-- I don't quite see the point of this
   \enspace
   \ignorespaces
 }{\par\medskip}
```

[image]

(BTW why are you defining this by hand if you load `amsthm`?)

Comment: Ah, I defined another environment in my native language but for MWE just called it Example environment :). Thank you very much campa